# Недопонимание с перемещением по строке

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

У нас есть два строковых массива `buf1` и `buf2`.

В массиве `buf1` содержится строка `"This is a string"`, а в `buf2` строка `"long "`(пробел тоже). Задача такова, чтобы перед словом `string` вставить слово `long`(включая пробел).

Автор книги реализует это следующим методом

```
std                  
mov edi, buf1+17+5     
mov esi, buf1+17       
mov ecx, 8
rep movsb
mov esi, buf2+4
mov ecx, 5
rep movsb
```

В принципе, мне непонятны только две строчки, а весь алгоритм здесь для наглядности.

Я не понимаю, зачем автор передвигается именно на `17+5` и `17` байт. Ведь длина `buf1` составляет `17` байт(включая 0-символ). Поэтому, если мы напишем  строку `buf1+17`, то мы попадаем на адрес, котортый слеубет за `0-символом`, то бишь:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
T h i s   i s   a   s  t  r  i  n  g  0  ...(сюда мы перемещаемся)
```

Ну и собственно вопрос, почему именно на 17 байт, а не на 16?

p.s. Пример взят из книги "Программирование на языке ассемблера NASM для ОС UNIX".

Comment: Там нет какого-нибудь завершающего символа? Может там в конце `0 0`?

Comment: Ну и возможна банальная ошибка

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, для `rep movs` нужен не 0 в конце, а длина (количество копируемых "единиц" - байт, слов, двойных слов) в `ecx`.

Comment: @Антон, добавьте в вопрос, как объявлены буферы.

Comment: @insolor Я знаю. Но мы же не знаем формат хранения строк, предложенный автором книги. Может у него там массивы строк? Тут вообще достаточно `+15`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov до этого примера идет объяснение команд movs, где берутся два строковых массива
buf1 resb 1024,
buf2 resb 1024

Comment: @AntonShchyrov но перед кодом примера, которой я описал, просто говорится, что берется два массива buf1 и buf2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего запустить под отладчиком и посмотреть. Тестовый код (fasm, под windows):

```
include 'win32ax.inc'

.code
start:
    std
    mov edi, buf1+17+5
    mov esi, buf1+17       
    mov ecx, 8
    rep movsb
    mov esi, buf2+4
    mov ecx, 5
    rep movsb
    ret

.data
    buf1 db "This is a string", 0, 1, 2
    align 16
    buf2 db "long "

.end start
```

После конца строки специально добавил данных, чтобы посмотреть, как будет копироваться.

Данные до выполнения кода:

[image: До выполнения]

После выполнения первого `rep movsb`:

[image: После 1]

Ну и после выполнения всего кода:

[image: В конце]

Видно что зачем-то копируется один лишний байт (1 после завершающего нуля первой строки). Возможно действительно просто ошибка. По факту (проверено отладчиком) достаточно такого кода:

```
std
mov edi, buf1+16+5
mov esi, buf1+16
mov ecx, 7
rep movsb
mov esi, buf2+4
mov ecx, 5
rep movsb
ret
```

Comment: В отладчике  под завершающим нулем понимается .(точка)?

Comment: @Антон, ascii представление в отладчиках/hex редакторах довольно условно. Нулевые байты обычно в них обозначаются точками. Лучше на hex dump ориентироваться.